# Compile Node/Express with Babel for production

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I have Node/Express server-side code that I'm running in development with `babel-node`. For production, I would like to compile this code so that it can be run without having to do so during runtime.

My server entry point is located at `server/index.js`. When I run `babel server/index.js` to just compile and print the compiled contents to stdout, my app just hangs indefinitely and doesn't print the compiled output. It prints `console.log` statements, so it seems that babel is *executing* the code and not *compiling* it.

Am I misunderstanding how to compile with babel?

*How do I compile a Node/Express app with Babel*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by running Babel with the binary located in node modules. Instead of running `babel index.js` I ran `node_modules/.bin/babel index.js`.